# How to create a bash script file in Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, echo

I wrote a script that the task is to create a text file and write into two lines.

This has been done, but more than once and I do not understand why because the script file does not contain any cycle and once the file is executed.

```
#!/bin/bash

<other, non-relevant variables and commands>

PHP_ROOT_DIR=/etc/php-5.6.22
PHP_CGI_WRAPPER=php-5622

mkdir -p $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin
touch $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER
echo -e "#!/bin/bash" >> $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER
echo -e "exec ${PHP_ROOT_DIR}/bin/php-cgi" >> $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER

<other, non-relevant variables and commands>

exit 0
```

output file content:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /etc/php-5.6.22/bin/php-cgi
#!/bin/bash
exec /etc/php-5.6.22/bin/php-cgi
#!/bin/bash
exec /etc/php-5.6.22/bin/php-cgi
```

#### Update:

This result occurs when run Docker container.

If I reduce my script to only of above part (removed non-relevant code parts), then working correctly on host OS and Docker in a container equally.

But the problem is still not fixed.

full version script file is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $(dirname $0)/create_vhost_config.sh
source $(dirname $0)/create_sample_html.sh

IP=$(ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}')

SRC_DIR=/usr/local/src

HTTPD_VERSION=2.4.20
HTTPD_ROOT_DIR=/etc/apache2
HTTPD_CONF_FILE=/etc/apache2/conf/apache2.conf

PHP_VERSION=5.6.22
PHP_ROOT_DIR=/etc/php-5.6.22
PHP_CGI_WRAPPER=php-5622



for i in 1 2
do
    mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/test$i/public
    mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/test$i/log  
    create_html ${IP} "test$i" "/var/www/vhosts/test$i/public/index.html"
    create_php_info "/var/www/vhosts/test$i/public/index.php"
    create_simple_vhost "test$i" "$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/test$i.home.conf"
done

# add PHP handler to Apache configuration
sed -i -e 's@    DirectoryIndex index.html@    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html@g' $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "\n<FilesMatch \"\.php$\">" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "\tSetHandler application/x-httpd-php" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "</FilesMatch>" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart

# *************************************** Creating PHP-CGI wrappers ***************************************
mkdir -p /var/www/cgi-bin
touch /var/www/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER
echo -e "#!/bin/bash" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER
echo -e "exec ${PHP_ROOT_DIR}/bin/php-cgi" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER

#restart apache
chmod -R +x /var/www/cgi-bin/

# *************************************** Configure with mod_cgi/mod_cgid ***************************************
sed -i -e 's@#LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so@LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so@g' $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
sed -i -e 's@#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so@LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so@g' $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "\nScriptAlias /php/ /var/www/cgi-bin/" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "\tRequire all granted" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo -e "</Directory>" >> $HTTPD_CONF_FILE

rm -rf $HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/*

for i in 1 2
do
    create_mod_cgi_conf "test$i" "/php/php-5622" "$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/test$i.home.conf"
done

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart


# *************************************** Configure with mod_fcgid ***************************************
cd $SRC_DIR
wget http://xenia.sote.hu/ftp/mirrors/www.apache.org//httpd/mod_fcgid/$(wget -O- http://xenia.sote.hu/ftp/mirrors/www.apache.org//httpd/mod_fcgid/ | egrep -o 'mod_fcgid-[0-9\.]+.tar.gz' | sort -V  | tail -1)
tar -xf mod_fcgid-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].tar.gz
cd mod_fcgid-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]
APXS=/etc/apache2/bin/apxs ./configure.apxs
make -j"$(nproc)"
make install

rm -rf $HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/*

for i in 1 2
do
    create_mod_fcgid_conf "test$i" "php-5622" "$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/test$i.home.conf"
done

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart


# Configure with FPM
find /var/www/vhosts/test*/public/ -exec chown daemon:daemon {} +
sed -i -e 's@#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so@LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so@g' $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
sed -i -e 's@#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so@LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so@g' $HTTPD_CONF_FILE
echo "include=etc/fpm.d/*.conf" >> $PHP_ROOT_DIR/etc/php-fpm.conf
cp $SRC_DIR/php-$PHP_VERSION/sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm $PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd
chmod 0700 $PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd
find /var/www/vhosts/test*/public/ -exec chown www-data:www-data {} +

rm -rf $PHP_ROOT_DIR/etc/fpm.d/*
rm -rf $HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/*

for i in 1 2
do
    create_php_fpmd_conf "test$i.home" "$IP" 5000$i "$PHP_ROOT_DIR/etc/fpm.d/test$i.home.conf"
    create_fpm_conf "test$i" "$IP" 5000$i "$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/conf/conf.d/test$i.home.conf"
done

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd start



# install Composer for PHP
cd /tmp
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/bin/php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | $PHP_ROOT_DIR/bin/php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd restart


#install PHP-PEAR
cd $SRC_DIR && \
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar -O go-pear.phar
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/bin/php go-pear.phar

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd restart


#install XDebug
setterm -bold on
cd $SRC_DIR
wget https://xdebug.org/files/$(wget -O- https://xdebug.org/files/ | egrep -o 'xdebug-[0-9\.]+.tgz' | sort -V  | tail -1)
tar -xvf xdebug-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].tgz
cd xdebug-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/bin/phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=$PHP_ROOT_DIR/bin/php-config
make -j"$(nproc)"
make install
echo $(find / -type d -name no-debug-zts*)/xdebug.so >> $PHP_ROOT_DIR/etc/php.ini

$HTTPD_ROOT_DIR/bin/apachectl restart
$PHP_ROOT_DIR/sbin/php-fpmd restart

exit 0
```

Comment: Since you are using `>> filename` it looks like you ran the file three times and content is being appended.

Comment: IS the file empty when you run the script...

Comment: @123
The file is created by the script:
touch $(dirname $ 0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER

Comment: @AdamP. touch only creates the file if it doesn't exist. All this will do is update the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

`echo -e "#!/bin/bash" >> $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER`

to this:

`echo -e "#!/bin/bash" > $(dirname $0)/cgi-bin/$PHP_CGI_WRAPPER`

[io-redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)